# Cannot refer facebook SDK from android app

Tags: android, facebook

i want to build an app which posts a simple textmessage on users facebook wall.
I tried to follow the step as specified in the link,
http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/.
 When i try to import and refer facebook SDk from my app, i am unable to import the files. Can i know any other alternative method?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried new project > project from existing source (under the android tab). Not sure if you need a newer version of Eclipse.

Comment: Hi, i am able to Import the facebook SDK to my workspace, but not able to REFER the facebook SDK from my app.can u please lets me know how to do it?